# error : uninitialized constant JiraController::JIRA4R

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed soap4r and jira4r.i can user jira4r::jiratool from a external ruby file. but while using the tool in a netbeans ruby on rails project i get the above error.
While doing bundle install i can see the jira4r and soap4r libraries being used but still code is not working.

i did gem 'soap4r' and gem 'jira4r' in the gem file
in the application.rb i did require 'jira4r'
I am using netbeans 6.9.1 in ubuntu 11.

Am i missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netbeans doesn't play nicely with rvm. It will be picking up the wrong gem set
It is really awkward to get netbeans to recognise the correct gem set.
See here for more details https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/netbeans/ and a solution but I haven't been able to get it work well enough for my liking.

It's a real PITA Sorry. I'm seriously considering changing my ide especially now that RoR is no longer officially supported in Netbeans 7 The netbeans plugin is now in the hands of the community but there does not seem to be much going on. Appologies to those that are making an effort.
http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubySupport